# How to start work on a new feature in Git that depends on another in progress feature

Tags: git, workflow, branching-and-merging

My development team has recently transitioned to Git from TFVC, and are following the GitHub Flow branching strategy. However, one developer believes they have found a flaw that makes Git "not suitable for real-world usage". The developer is going to do a pull request to bring a feature to master, but then immediately needs to start work on another feature which expands on the first one.

They are asking they we disable the policies protecting the master branch so they can complete the first PR immediately without having to wait for review. The idea being that once the PR is complete they could create a new branch off master and continue to work on the feature without having to be stuck waiting for other people. However, the way I see it they can:

1. Continue working on the "phase 2" on the feature on the same
   branch if there is no need to deploy the first part of the feature
   on its own. Submit the PR once the feature is completely done.
2. Create a new branch off master, and merge the first feature branch to it. May need to do further merges or rebase if changes are made during review.
3. Create a new branch off the first feature branch, rebase it to master once the first PR is complete.

Do these options make sense? What is the recommended approach between 2 and 3, or is there another better way?

Comment: Approach 3 makes the most sense to me, there's no reason anything needs to be forced into master without review - master is your failsafe. Is there some reason they can't just push the phased branch and have people work from it until it's ready for a master merge?

Comment: In reality this isn't a git issue - it's a code review policy. The bigger issue is that if you skip it once, then you'll skip it again. Code quality will suffer, later reversions and backtracking will become more 'public' and make following code progression harder, and someone will push junk by accident at least once.

Comment: @mdawsondev I will recommend approach 3 if they insist on getting the first phase into master. They are only dev working on this feature (both phases) so there is no technical reason why they can't keep working on the branch until its ready for a master merge.

Comment: @match I completely agree, which is why I want to make sure it doesn't happen. We didn't have a code review process or policy before we moved to Git, and it has been quite a challenge to get developers to buy into it. This particular developer has been very resistant about having their code reviewed, and will be going to management to try to get the greenlight to bypass review in order to workaround this "git" issue.